# Appengine using https instead of http

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webrtc

I have recently installed the apprtc.appspot.com demo from https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/, and have installed it at http:// [my-app-name].appspot.com. I have found that if I access the app using the http:// prefix, the app is always served on https://.

Additionally, if I set up a custom domain and then access the app, I get a "SSL connection error" (which is not surprising since I don't have SSL enabled for this app -- and doing so would require using Google Apps which is a cost that I don't want to incur right now)

I would like to serve the app without using SSL -- is this possible? Additionally, I would like to know why the http:// is being replaced with an https:// when I try to connect to the server, as this does not happen with any of my other apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your app.yaml file. It must have this line somewhere:

```
secure: always
```

It tells App Engine to serve your app using SSL.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the problem. I have uploaded a new version following your suggestion and it appears to work.